# Rotating a chart Back Image

Tags: c#

I am a newbie to c# trying to rotate a Back Image on a chart using a track bar. I have the actual rotation solved, but I am having an issue with overwriting the file so that it can be rotated as many times as the user wants. Currently, it will rotate by one increment on the track bar, and then crash. Here is what I currently have. The image variable is just the original image.

```
private void trackBar2_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image rotatedImage = RotateImage(image, trackBar2.Value);
    rotatedImage.Save(Path.GetFullPath("Image_Rotated.png"));
    chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].BackImage = Path.GetFullPath("Image_Rotated.png");
    rotatedImage.Dispose();    
}
```

The idea was to have the original image that would always be the same, and a second image that would be the original image, just rotated and saved over every time, then set as the Back Image. The fact that it crashes on the second time it goes through this method leads me to believe that it is a problem with the saving of the file, rather than the RotateImage method.

Comment: Yes, it looks as if the Chart sits on the file handles of each image it has ever shown. This would make your approach impossible unless one can force the release of the handles..? Can you create a few rotations in advance or do you need too many?